# Reduce line spacing between headers?

Tags: html, css, header

I want to have 2 headlines to be next to each other and I don't understand why HTML automatically adds blank space in between.
I want the space at the red arrows to go away.

[image: This is what it looks like now and the arrows indicate what I want to move together]

HTML

```
    <body>
       <h1>Der Gecko<h1>                
       <h2>(lat. Gekko gecko)<h2>
    <body>
```

CSS

```
h1 {    
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #9B26AF;
  color: #50ffffff;
  font-size: 175;
}   

H2 {    
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #68EFAD;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your padding and margin values?
Try it with 0.

Comment: Please add a little more context to your answer, since the user is new to HTML/CSS markup and coding, like explaining that probably there is more CSS involved that is affecting the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

in `CSS` the heading elements display as `block`.
 to achieve your approch you should change its style display to `display:inline;`

```
h1{
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #9B26AF;
    color: #50ffffff;
    font-size: 175;
    display:inline;
}

h2{
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #68EFAD;
    color: black;
    font-size: 50;
    display:inline;
}
```